# The need to use logic level converter

Tags: power, voltage-level

Why do we need level logic converter to have 5V or 3.3V?

Because in Arduino Uno/Mega (don't know about other boards), they already provide 5V and 3.3V for us to use.

Comment: please explain the context for your question?  (the reason for your question)

Comment: Is this about i2c?

Answer (score 5):

Level logic converting for level shifting is different from powering a device.

Logic level is the state of a digital input/output. No voltage (or very little of it) is considered `LOW`.   Over the threshold voltage is `HIGH`. On a 3.3V system, if you set pin to `HIGH`, it has 3.3 V.  On a 5 V system, `HIGH` is 5 V.

A digital input pin reads `HIGH` once the threshold voltage is surpassed. If the input pin is for 3.3 V and doesn't have 5 V tolerance, feeding 5 V as `HIGH` could destroy it.  That is why you need level converter from 5 V to 3.3 V.

If the input pin is for 5 V and the threshold voltage is higher then 3.3 V,  3.3 V input will not be read as `HIGH`.  That is when you need level converter from 3.3 V to 5 V.

You must consult the 3.3 V device datasheet and check if the input pins are 5 V tolerant.   You should also check the digital pin threshold voltage on a 5 V device in case you want to communicate with it using 3.3 V.